# Tab Control Accessing each tab member Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

How can I hide a button when a specific tab is clicked?

for example I have 4 tabs what should I do whenever I click tab 1 a certain button in my
form will disappear?

i've tried using `if(tabControl.SelectedIndex == 1){ button1.Visible = false; }` but it doesn't work. T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Click` event on that particular `TabPage`

```
yourTabControl.TabPages[1].Click += (s, e) => button1.Visible = false;
```

Just remember to show it again when the time is appropriate.

Or better yet, just listen for when the selected tab changes:

```
yourTabControl.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) => {
    if (yourTabControl.SelectedIndex == 1)
        button1.Visible = false;
    } else {
        button1.Visible = true;
    }
};
```

Or more simply:

```
yourTabControl.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) => 
       button1.Visible = yourTabControl.SelectedIndex != 1;
```